# How can I set multiple values to local variables in a Module?

Tags: scoping

Multiple assignment is supported by `Set`. 
How can do something similar in `Module` expressions?
If I could do it, whould there be drawbacks?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
g[x11_, y11_] := {xx111, yy111} = {x11, y11}

g[x11_, y11_] := Module[{{x111, y111} = {x11, y11}}, 1]

g[1, 2]
```

> Module::lvset: Local variable specification {{x111, y111} = {1, 2}} contains {x111, y111} = {1, 2}, which is an assignment to {x111,y111}; only assignments to symbols are allowed. >>

Possible alternatives are:

```
ggg[x11_, y11_] := 
  Module[{xx = {x11, y11}, x1, x2}, {x1 = xx[[2]], x2 = xx[[1]]}]
```

or

```
ggg[x11_, y11_] := Module[{x1111=x11, y1111=y11}, what... ]
```

Comment: "only assignments to symbols are allowed" - that's right, the scoping constructs don't allow parallel assignment in the variable list.

Comment: In [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373526/error-generating-localized-variables-as-constants/8377522#8377522) to a similar question about `With` on SO, I posted a macro which can do this. You can just replace `With` with `Module` there, if that kind of solution fits you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As J.M. points out in his comment, the kind of multiple assignment you want is simply not supported. The closest you can get (and it is perfectly serviceable in my opinion) is

```
g[x11_, y11_] := Module[{x111, y111},
  {x111, y111} = {x11, y11};
  1]
```

Comment: en, seems declare variables and then assign separately. Anyway, this is not big problem, I just take some habits from one function elsewhere.

Comment: @Hyper, yes, that's precisely what m_goldberg does. That's how it is...